# How to enable ANSI colors with Log4j2 on Windows Terminal?

Tags: java, log4j, ansi-colors

Unlike CMD and PowerShell, the new [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal) supports ANSI colors out of the box. A quick test program can confirm that things are working:

```
public class Color {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\u001b[32mHello, World\n\u001b[0m");
    }
}
```

Log4j2 doesn't seem to be picking up on this though. I have this sequence in my PatternLayout:

```
%highlight{%-5level}{FATAL=bg_red white, ERROR=red, WARN=yellow, INFO=green, DEBUG=blue}
```

This works on macOS and Linux, but not Windows. Looking at the [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html), I have `disableAnsi` and `noConsoleNoAnsi`, but the defaults seem to be what I want and explicitly setting them doesn't have any effect.

I did make sure that I included JANSI in my project, even though I didn't think it should be necessary, but it also doesn't make any difference.

What option am I missing to get the colors to work?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#enable-jansi), I used the system property `log4j.skipJansi`.

In Gradle you can for example modify system properties for `test` tasks as follows (using Kotlin DSL):

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    systemProperty("log4j.skipJansi", "false")
}

// don't forget to add jANSI to your dependencies
dependencies {
    :
    api(group = "org.fusesource.jansi", name = "jansi", version = "1.18")
}
```